# Dump Xorg's output on console after exit X

Tags: xorg

I start X using xinit and fire `startx` from consle, switch back and forth between X and console but after leave GUI/X to back to console, amount of X's log lay on console's output.

I try to redirect `startx='startx &> /dev/null`, doesn't work because it invokes  `X` / `/usr/bin/X`, it's X echo output.

I do `X='X &>/dev/null`, don't work either.

So how to silent output of X in console after leave GUI/X?

Answer (score 0):

Log data usually go to standard error, which you have not redirected.  It is as simple as that.

Comment: I did `2>&1 > /dev/null`, didn't work.